# Exiting a shell script from inside a while loop

Tags: linux, shell

I'm writing a simple shell script that should exit with 0 if an input string is found in a file, and exit with 1 if it isn't

```
INPSTR=$1

cat ~/file.txt | while read line
do
    if [[ $line == *$INPSTR* ]]; then
        exit 0
    fi
done

#string not found
exit 1
```

What's actually happening is that when the string is found, the loop exits, and the shell then goes to "exit 1". What's the correct way to exit from the shell script entirely while in a loop?

Comment: It's not the while loop that messes it up, it's the pipe. `true | exit` won't exit your script either.

Comment: Subshell's yo. You are exiting only the subshell generated by your pipe.

Comment: BTW, BashFAQ #24 is related: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Answer (score 13):

You need to avoid creating sub-shell in your script by avoiding the pipe and un-necessary `cat`:

```
INPSTR="$1"

while read -r line
do
    if [[ $line == *"$INPSTR"* ]]; then
        exit 0
    fi
done < ~/file.txt

#string not found
exit 1
```

Otherwise `exit 0` is only exiting from the sub-shell created by pipe and later when loop ends then `exit 1` is used from parent shell.

Comment: Good catch on quoting the pattern. Not much point to quoting the right-hand-side of the assignment, but I grok trying to showcase good practices. (On which point, I personally would use `=` rather than `==` to discourage development of muscle memory incompatible with POSIX `test` / `[`).

Comment: If it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 8):

you can catch return code of subshell using $? like this

```
INPSTR=$1
cat ~/file.txt | while read line
do
if [[ $line == *$INPSTR* ]]; then
    exit 0
fi
done
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    exit 0
else
#string not found
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for real variant for exit without double check in and after loop.
I came up for simular task. To exit from whole script we can kill its task by pid. But need to get pid very carefully so not killing some important parent-parent id.
The pid of loop must be $BASHPID, and the ppid (pid of script) will be $$ (if no more subshells used) So in this case command is

`kill -9 $$`

or if your shell child survives after killing parent it can be

`kill -9 $$ $BASHPID`